# Google Adwords API. How to get AdID from Shopping Performance Report

Tags: google-ads-api, google-shopping-api

I am using shopping perfomance report. There are only adgroupid, but how to get adid?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Shopping Campaigns is purely based on *Product Group* created under *AdGroup*, which is lowest entity in the hierarchy. So you'll not able to get report for *Ad* level and rather report will be at *Product Group* level under *AdGroup ID*.